# Avoid realoading a page when user refresh or press F5 button

Tags: reactjs

I have react page with table. Table has a column with hyperlink when I click on a particular hyperlink new page open with details about the clicked hyperlink or row.

```
<Route exact path="/employeedetails" element={<EmployeeDetails />} />
```

I want to avoid reloading Employee Details page when user refresh or press F5. Or How can I capture a refresh event and call the React component.

Comment: There's no way to stop a user from refreshing a page, sure you can put some restraints to keyboard events but that's about it.

Answer (score 2):

I had experienced same problem. Here is the some of solutions but there is no perfect way to block the refreshing as I know.

1. block F5 keyCode

```
const blockRefresh = (e) => {
  if ((e.which || e.keyCode) == 116) e.preventDefault();
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", blockRefresh);
```

It will perfectly block the F5, if not, check the keyCode.

2. set Beforeunload eventhandler

```
const blockRefresh = (e) => {
  return "block Refresh"
}

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", blockRefresh);
```

But, when you click the browser refresh button, it will be refreshed if there are routing history.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the window `beforeunload` event:

```
function onBeforeUnload($event){

}
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", onBeforeUnload);
```

You can know more about that event [click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)